# Ошибка при преобразовании конкретного класса к обобщенному интерфейсу

Tags: c#, .net

У меня есть модели:

```
public class ModelA
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class ModelB : ModelA
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class ModelC
{
    public string Result {get;set;}
}
```

Обобщенный интерфейс:

```
public interface ISample<T, TResult> where T : ModelA where TResult : ModelC
{
   Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> Do(IEnumerable<T> models);
}
```

Реализация:

```
public class Sample: ISample<ModelB, ModelC>
{
   Task<IEnumerable<ModelC>> Do(IEnumerable<ModelB> models) {//Do..}
}
```

И некая фабрика:

```
public static class SampleFactory
{
        private readonly static Dictionary<Type, ISample<ModelA, ModelC>> samples = InitDictionary();

        public static ISample<ModelA, ModelC> Get(Type sampleType)
        {
            return samples[sampleType];
        }

        private static Dictionary<Type, ISample<ModelA, ModelC>> InitDictionary()
        {
            return new()
            {
                samples[typeof(Sample)] = (ISample<ModelA, ModelC>)new Sample();
            }
        }
 }
```

Проблема: компилируется без каких либо ошибок, но в рантайме, при запросе объекта из фабрики выкидывает исключение: невозможно преобразовать из Sample в ISample<ModelA, ModelC>. Подскажите в чем здесь проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Невозможно преобразовать из `Sample` в `ISample<ModelA, ModelC>` потому что он `ISample<ModelB, ModelC>`. Апкаст на дженериках не работает, он работает только на основных типах. То есть то что вы хотите, в чистом виде работать не может.

Самое очевидное решение здесь - это `Dictionary<Type, object>`. Но ваш пример сильно обфусцирован до такой степени, что я вообще не вижу смысла в словаре внутри фабрики, так как он согласно этому коду может иметь только один ключ, смысловая часть всей задумки потеряна при обфускации.

Comment: Да, действительно, сильно ужал пример. Но смысл в том, что классов, реализующих ISample и моделей, наследованных от ModelA несколько поэтому и в словаре фабрики будет несколько ключей.

Comment: @Lebedev_VA вы добились усложнения этой всей истории до такой степени, что захотели наследования в обобщении, но его там нет, не было и не будет. Упрощайте, думайте над архитектурой. Как именно нужно сделать - известно только вам. Почему у вас ModelC никак не связана с двумя другими - загадка, метод `Do` сможет скушать любую модель и выплюнуть любой результат? Наверное он очень сложный, а если нет, то где-то перегнули палку с этими обобщениями. Не путайте обобщение с абстракцией. Обобщение и наследование - 2 большие разницы и задачи они решают совершенно разные.